# How Should I Extend My Range Higher As a Bass?

Tags: technique, bass-voice

I was wondering how I should extend my range higher as a bass singer. Right now, I can sing as low as a B2, but I cannot sing very high at all. I can technically hit all the notes towards the top of the bass clef, but they don't have the same rich sound and support as the low notes do. I need these higher notes when I'm singing with a choir or by myself, so I think I should work on making them more supported and comfortable in my range. Any suggestions/techniques?

Keep in mind that I have only been singing for a few years. Also, I am only 15 years old, so my voice is still developing.

Comment: You know that a B2 is not a low note at all?

Answer (score 3):

Something that you may want to do is *slowly* work your voice into a higher range, by slowly trying to make yourself sing higher. For example, try practicing something that you think is slightly higher than you're comfortable with. You could try singing a Bass 1 or a Tenor 2 part if you sing Bass 2 for a majority of your choir's pieces.

Another recommendation that I have is just to *wait.* You're still 15, your voice is developing and growing, and just remember that voice will (most likely) change until you're in your mid-20's.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the fact you are a bass singer makes a difference to the question of trying to sing higher - I think that singing higher could be a goal of both basses or tenors, and so I offer some general advice for singing higher.

First off, do you understand what your falsetto is? Every male singer has a falsetto, and while you may never be able to sing some of the high tenor sweet tones in some popular songs, it is still worth seeing if you can extend your falsetto. There are other questions on this site (and surely resources elsewhere) that can help you to extend your falsetto.

While I don't have much experience teaching singing, I think it might be good to consider placement also. It isn't proper singing to always sing from the chest, so if you are doing that, try moving the sound into your head - or toward the front of your mouth and not down in your throat. Hooting like an owl is one way to see the difference immediately. The sound of your voice will be brighter the farther forward in your mouth it is, and you will certainly extend your range by using your head!

As the other answer by Snoooot mentions, it would be good to just work it higher by singing higher. You don't even have to find music necessarily - why not pretend you are a monk and sing your own [gregorian chant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_chant), and slowly get a little higher each time?

If you are serious about singing, try joining a choir or find an outlet for your voice. You will get much better advice in person.

Answer (score 0):

Always important to have good breath support from your diaphragm.  Practice breathing by laying flat on the your back on the floor.  Place your right hand on your tummy.  When you take a breath your hand should move upward and your shoulders should not be moving.  Same thing should happen when you are breathing for singing or playing a wind instrument when you are standing up.  Very little movement in the shoulders and chest but your stomach should bulge out as the diaphragm moves down.  This gives good support to your voice or wind instrument.
Larry